# file binding with docker-compose inside a containered gitlab runner

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**What I want:**

Execute `docker-compose up -d` within a gitlab runner and bind files from repository to the container.

**My configuration:**

*docker-compose.yml* creates the following containers:

- gitlab
- gitlab-runner

A new repository that contains

- *gitlab-ci.yml* that executes `docker-compose up -d`
- config.toml
- *docker-compose.yml* that should bind the config.toml from the repo to the container

**My Problem:**

Since the docker socket is bound to the host system the `docker-compose` is not executed in the context of the repository but in a context somewhere in the host system. The other files from the repo are not yet copied to the host system. So the composer cannot find them, hence the `config.toml` is not existing in the container. If I create manually a `test.config` somewhere in the host system and put the path into the `docker-compose.yml` of my repository, it works. But I want to use the file from my repo.

Comment: Dockerfile can copy contents from place to place. You can include reference to relative dockefile via build: context: .

Comment: How to copy data from the repository to the host system, while the docker file is stored in my repository but is executed within the host system?

Comment: oh i see what you mean. I think that is an anti pattern since you can share the data via a volume to the host.

Comment: Yeah, I would prefer sharing via volume binding, but how can I do this?